# How to combine strings in rows based on position condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, combinations

It proved difficult to find search terms for this kind of question.
I need to write a script that can make **all** combinations of strings of each row in a data frame. It should use each string **once**, and only make combinations of strings that are **two steps** away from the first one. **The first and the last** column are in reality next to each other. Hence they can also not be combined (it is a circle of strings in reality). This same script needs to be applied to data frames of different even amounts of columns, here is an example with 8.

I have only managed to make it manually for a data frame with a given number of column, but not an expression that would work for a data frame of any number of columns.

This is the type of data:

```
  Crop_1    Crop_2      Crop_3      Crop_4  Crop_5 Crop_6 Crop_7 Crop_8
1 Potato     Onion   Sugarbeet Grassclover Cabbage Potato  Wheat Carrot
2 Potato Sugarbeet Grassclover      Potato Cabbage  Onion Carrot  Wheat
```

The desired outcome in this case should be these 6 options:

```
                  Pair_1            Pair_2              Pair_3             Pair_4 Crop_1    Crop_2      Crop_3      Crop_4  Crop_5 Crop_6 Crop_7 Crop_8
1   Potato-Sugarbeet Onion-Grassclover       Cabbage-Wheat      Potato-Carrot Potato     Onion   Sugarbeet Grassclover Cabbage Potato  Wheat Carrot
2 Potato-Grassclover  Sugarbeet-Potato      Cabbage-Carrot        Onion-Wheat Potato Sugarbeet Grassclover      Potato Cabbage  Onion Carrot  Wheat
3       Potato-Wheat      Onion-Carrot   Sugarbeet-Cabbage Grassclover-Potato Potato     Onion   Sugarbeet Grassclover Cabbage Potato  Wheat Carrot
4      Potato-Carrot   Sugarbeet-Wheat Grassclover-Cabbage       Potato-Onion Potato Sugarbeet Grassclover      Potato Cabbage  Onion Carrot  Wheat
5     Potato-Cabbage      Onion-Potato     Sugarbeet-Wheat Grassclover-Carrot Potato     Onion   Sugarbeet Grassclover Cabbage Potato  Wheat Carrot
6     Potato-Cabbage   Sugarbeet-Onion  Grassclover-Carrot       Potato-Wheat Potato Sugarbeet Grassclover      Potato Cabbage  Onion Carrot  Wheat
```

The data frame can be retrieved here:

```
structure(list(Crop_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Potato", class = "factor"), 
    Crop_2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Onion", "Sugarbeet"), class = "factor"), 
    Crop_3 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Grassclover", "Sugarbeet"
    ), class = "factor"), Crop_4 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Grassclover", 
    "Potato"), class = "factor"), Crop_5 = structure(c(1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "Cabbage", class = "factor"), Crop_6 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Onion", 
    "Potato"), class = "factor"), Crop_7 = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Carrot", 
    "Wheat"), class = "factor"), Crop_8 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Carrot", 
    "Wheat"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: To be clear, you only actually will get two rows from your provided dataframe? Does the ordering matter, i.e. you need crops 1 and 3 to be in pair 1?

Comment: Actually I am totally unclear on how the crops map to pairs. In row 1, I expect to see potato_sugarbeet, onion_grassclover, but then where is sugarbeet_cabbage (crop 3 to crop 5)? And I would expect to see 8 pairs for 8 input crops, not 4 (each crop can be mapped to the crop two down)

Comment: It seems as though maybe you are treating the crops in groups of 4, so you give 1:3, 2:4, then 5:7, 6:8. but then you need to have a number of crops divisible by 4, not just even

Comment: Thanks. Answers to the comments in order:
1. The ordering per se is not that important. As long as each crop is used once and all crops are used.
2.   3-5 is not used as the sugarbeet has already been used with the pair with potato. Again, each crop should just be used once, that is why 4 pairs for 8 crops.
3. Groups of 4 are not necessarily needed. I thought i had made all the possible combinations, but i might be wrong. With more columns 10, 12 and so on the options for making combinations would become more.

Comment: If you only use each crop once, then it's unclear why you would choose to keep the pairs 1:3, 2:4, 5:7, 6:8 as you have done over a different set such as 3:5, 4:6, 7:1, 8:2 (since you said that 8 and 1 are adjacent). There are 8 total pairs but you just want to keep a set of four that uses each number once, and it doesn't matter which one?

Comment: The order that the crops are mentioned in the pair does not matter. It is okay to pair 1 and 7, and 2 and 8 as in your example.
Indeed, i want to make sets of four that uses each number once and pairs must be made at least two steps away from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does the trick. What you need to deal with is even numbers that are divisible by four, and those that aren't. For those that are divisible by four, you can just group them into fours and take two pairs as you have done. We use `seq.int` to get the starts of each pair, and then use `setdiff` to get the ends. For those that aren't, treat the first 6 specially (matching 1-4, 2-5, 3-6) and then do the rest like the fours.

The rest of the complexity is just making sure that you can accept a `tibble` and return a `tibble`, since that's what's expected by `nest` and `unnest`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- structure(list(Crop_1 = c("Potato", "Potato"), Crop_2 = c("Onion", "Sugarbeet"), Crop_3 = c("Sugarbeet", "Grassclover"), Crop_4 = c("Grassclover", "Potato"), Crop_5 = c("Cabbage", "Cabbage"), Crop_6 = c("Potato", "Onion"), Crop_7 = c("Wheat", "Carrot"), Crop_8 = c("Carrot", "Wheat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

pair_crops <- function(crop_row) {
  crop_set <- as.character(crop_row)
  n_crops <- length(crop_set)
  if (n_crops %% 2 == 1) {
    stop("Odd number of crops!")
  } else if (n_crops %% 4 == 0) {
    starts <- sort(c(seq.int(1, n_crops, 4), seq.int(2, n_crops, 4)))
  } else {
    starts <- sort(c(1:3,seq.int(7, n_crops, 4), seq.int(8, n_crops, 4)))
  }
  ends <- setdiff(1:n_crops, starts)
  tibble(
    pair = str_c(crop_set[starts], "-", crop_set[ends]),
    name = str_c("Pair_", 1:length(starts))
  ) %>%
    spread(name, pair)
}

tbl %>%
  rowid_to_column %>%
  nest(-rowid, .key = "crop") %>%
  mutate(pairs = map(crop, pair_crops)) %>%
  unnest()
#>   rowid Crop_1    Crop_2      Crop_3      Crop_4  Crop_5 Crop_6 Crop_7
#> 1     1 Potato     Onion   Sugarbeet Grassclover Cabbage Potato  Wheat
#> 2     2 Potato Sugarbeet Grassclover      Potato Cabbage  Onion Carrot
#>   Crop_8             Pair_1            Pair_2         Pair_3        Pair_4
#> 1 Carrot   Potato-Sugarbeet Onion-Grassclover  Cabbage-Wheat Potato-Carrot
#> 2  Wheat Potato-Grassclover  Sugarbeet-Potato Cabbage-Carrot   Onion-Wheat
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This gives the combinations as given in row 1 and 2 in my expected output data frame. For 5 and 6 i was using : lapply(1:(ncol(data)/2), function(x) paste0(data[[x]], "-", data[[ x + ncol(data) / 2]])) %>% data.frame What about solution 3 and 4? Do you mean i have to manually change the seq.int in the formula to get those? If this would be applied at data frames with 6,10, or 12 crops, this same function would also work? I will have to take a look at that.

Comment: It should work for any number of crops, but you didn't provide that input data. The logic is, if it divides by four, do 1-3, 2-4, 5-7, 6-8 and so on. If it doesn't divide by 6, then do 1-4, 2-5, 3-6, and then 7-9, 8-10, 11-13, 12-14 and so on.